# Is it possible to know which topic a message was received on in Akka's "Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster"?

Tags: java, akka, distributed, publish-subscribe

I have an Akka system with Actors representing sensors. Every time a sensor makes an observation, its corresponding Actor publishes this observation on an internal pub/sub topic. This makes it easy to extend usages of the observation (saved in a DB by one Actor, published to an MQTT broker by another, etc.)

A possible solution to make the receiver aware of which topic it received the message on, is to include the topic in the message. However, this seems like bad design to me. Is it possible to see which topic the current message was received on in an Actor in Akka?

Akka's documentation on Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/distributed-pub-sub.html) does not mention this as far as I can see.

Comment: I do not know about Akka framework but in generalized publisher/subscriber messaging, it is possible to include meta-information on the message itself. In this case an attribute to the meta-info could be the logical topic name. Now from a design perspective it may not be a bad dssign as you put it, however, if the logical topic names are dynamic then the Actor needs to be configurable to take the name or if discoverable, discover it.

Comment: The reason why I argue it might be bad design to include the topic which the message is sent to in the message itself is because it is duplicated information. If the topic is available somewhere, that is.

Comment: Duplicating information per se is not a bad thing, duplicating information that reduces complexity of a system and there by improve maintenability can certainly be considered, if you take the classical case of DB higher normal form, which can be achieved in many systems but is not brought to play because it makes data retrieval and queries complicated and sometime has performance bottlenecks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is not built in as a feature of Distributed Pub/Sub. I typically would solve this by making some sort of envelope:

```
case class PubSubEnvelope[MessageType](topic: String, payload: MessageType)
```

For extra safety, perhaps you'd want to make some sort of supertype for `MessageType` so that you could constrain it, and some enum-like structure for `topic` instead of `String`.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by using the sender() reference, as this suited my topic structure. But in general this is probably the way to do it. Thanks!